# What happened with server code on deployment to Heroku

Tags: javascript, multiplayer, webapp

I'm starting to learn about making games on the web and am using this agario clone on GitHub to help.

I've succeeded in setting up a version on Heroku using the instructions from [here](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone/wiki/Setup). I've never used Heroku before, so I'm a little lost on a few more things. The link from the instructions allowed the files to be directly transferred from GitHub. However, I can't seem to view them at all from Heroku - I can only run the client with 'Open app' (which works).

What exactly happened when I deployed the app? Did Heroku immediately start running the [server code](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone/blob/master/src/server/server.js) and will it continue to indefinitely do so even if no clients are connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's gear will have started up and started running your node.js instance. Node.Js is designed to run continuously, but depending on your [pricing plan](https://www.heroku.com/pricing), heroku may shut down the 'Gear'(your server instance) if nothing changes in 30 minutes.